# Random Sampling with overall probabilities

Tags: probability

I know how to have weighted draw of a single value from a set of $n$ items, given a probability $p_i$ with $1 \leq i \leq n$.

What I would like to do is to draw a subset of m items ($m \leq n$) from the original set, such that each item is drawn with a probability of $q_i$ ($\sum q_i = m$).

How can I compute the probabilities $p$ for each draw within a round of drawing, such that I end up with the probabilities provided in $q$?

Just to clarify here a short example: if I choose $m=2$ from $n=3$ (A,B,C) and the probabilities are $q=(A:1.0, B:0.5, C:0.5)$, then A must be selected on every round, so a selection of (B,C) is impossible. On $q=(A:0.8, B:0.7, C:0.5)$, then A is included in 80% of the result sets, B in 70% and C in 50%.